# Calculate a new pandas DataFrame from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I am wondering what would be the pandas-way to compute a new table from them. My second table is simply a reversed transposition of the first:

```
Exchange   Ticker     Price
0  bittrex  BCH/BTC  0.158647
2   kraken  BCH/BTC  0.158690
1     gdax  BCH/BTC  0.158760
3  binance  BCH/BTC  0.159110
                3        1        2         0
Exchange  binance     gdax   kraken   bittrex
Ticker    BCH/BTC  BCH/BTC  BCH/BTC   BCH/BTC
Price     0.15911  0.15876  0.15869  0.158647
```

I wish to calculate the percentage difference between the Price values of both tables and populate this data into a new table e.g. https://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/arbitrage/USD

With the difference being ((Price B - Price A)/Price B)*100

Do I need to create a 2D array and calculate these values myself or is there a better way with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want an all-pairs comparison matrix, like this?

```
i, j = df.Price.values, df.Exchange.values 
df2 = pd.DataFrame((i - i[:, None]) / i * 100, index=j, columns=j)
```

```
df2

          bittrex    kraken      gdax   binance
bittrex  0.000000  0.027097  0.071177  0.290994
kraken  -0.027104  0.000000  0.044092  0.263968
gdax    -0.071227 -0.044111  0.000000  0.219974
binance -0.291843 -0.264667 -0.220459  0.000000
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for and in two whole lines, my solution had 20 :) Thank you very much. This library is very powerful once you know how to use it

Comment: @FreddieH Yes, it certainly helps to have a good understanding of the library. And not just pandas, but numpy too, they complement each other, and can be used interchangeably to create some powerful code.